# I am getting error when I try to run VBScript file in Automation Anywhere Code

Tags: rpa, automationanywhere

I am executing a VBscript file that includes code to pickup latest file from folder. when I run this script in task editor code, it is giving a pop up from "Windows Script Host" saying "Error in script - object not a collection".

All other VBscript files that are recorded using SAP tool are working except for this file.

this same VBscript file is executing in another environment of Automation anywhere as well. issue persists when I execute it on my current environment.

Can anyone please guide me on this please??

Comment: ..and the script you are trying to run is?

Comment: As @RoelStrolenberg mentioned without a script it's hard to tell. Perhaps this can give you some clues. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/779f2985-7156-4e32-b2be-a824b3be3c30/object-is-not-a-collection-error?forum=ITCG

Answer (score 0):

TBH this sounds like a VBScript issue rather than an AA issue; it sounds like you have something in your script that is referencing a specific environment.

Have you run the script successfully on the same machine *outside* of AA (IE from the command line)?

I would recommend trying that first if you haven't already.

Logging to a text file from within the script can also be a valuable tool to help you see exactly what's happening when you're running the script from within an AA task.

Unfortunately, this is less helpful if your issue is file I/O in general, so I would recommend making sure that you can correctly execute a simple file I/O VBscript from within an AA task before trying to debug more complicated code.